# Xcode 4: How can I reference project variables/macros in a file template?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

Ok, so, I've got a relatively complex project template hierarchy that defines code style related macros and variables (curlies on same or new line, indentation, etc).  [My code style template will probably give more context](https://github.com/nevir/xcode-templates/blob/xcode-4.5/Project%20Templates/Common/Code%20Style.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist)

Works great when generating a project.

However, I'm not seeing a clear path to reusing these macros/variables when generating new files after the project has been built.  Findings so far:

- macros and variables defined at the project level are not substituted when referenced in a file template
- popup option definitions in file templates do not seem to support complex definitions (e.g. defining a macro when the drop down is in a given state)
- project variables *do* appear to become defaults for options of the same name in the file template wizard
- file templates don't appear to be able to define other templates as ancestors

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following line:
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions '{ "ORGANIZATIONNAME" = "Your Company Name" ; }'
into a Terminal window, replacing "Your Company Name" with whatever you choose.
You can also open the file at ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Xcode in "Property List Editor" and insert your company name as a string value for the key "ORGANIZATIONNAME" under the dictionary "PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions". You may need to create "PBXCustomTemplateMacroDefinitions" at the top level if it doesn't already exist.